# How to create a constraint on only part of a composite key for a bit field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table with a composite key of `[PersonId]` and `[LanguageId]`, and a third column of `[IsPrimary]`. A person can speak more than one language, but they can only have exactly one primary language (yay business requirements!).

How do I create a constraint that allows for `[IsPrimary]` to be true only once for each unique [PersonId]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_personid_languageid on t(personid)
    where isprimary = 1;
```